# How to merge two arrays containing objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

There is an array A:

```
   let arrA = [{
      name: 'twitter',
      active: true
    }, {
      name: 'medium',
      active: false
    },
     {
      name: 'platinum',
      active: false
    }
  ];
```

And array B:

```
let arrB = [{
      name: 'twitter',
      active: false
    }, {
      name: 'medium',
      active: false
    }
  ];
```

How can I end up with an array that looks like this:

```
let newArr = [{
      name: 'twitter',
      active: true
    }, {
      name: 'medium',
      active: false
    },
    {
      name: 'platinum',
      active: false
    }
  ];
```

I need that `active` property of objects in `newArr` is equal to an `or` between `active` property of objects of `arrA` and `arrB` where the `name` is the same.

`arrA` and `arrB` can have of different length

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: @MuratK. I need to merge an array of objects not of strings. If you can provide me another answer related I will close this question

Comment: Changed the tags to JavaScript as there's literally nothing specific to TypeScript in this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is my approach. Using map

```
const arrA = [{
    name: 'twitter',
    active: true
}, {
    name: 'medium',
    active: false
},{
    name: 'platinum',
    active: false
}];

const arrB = [{
    name: 'twitter',
    active: false
}, {
    name: 'medium',
    active: false
}];

  const allItems = arrA.concat(arrB);
  const mergedItems = new Map();
  allItems.forEach((value) => {
    if (!mergedItems.get(value.name)) {
      mergedItems.set(value.name, value);
    } else {
      value.active = value.active || mergedItems.get(value.name).active;
      mergedItems.set(value.name, value);
    }
  });
  const mergedArray =  Array.from(mergedItems.values()) ;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty array: `var newArr = [];`
2. Push object into `newArr` where object key and value are compared between `arrA` and `arrB`.
3. Done.

```js
let arrA = [
      {
        name: 'twitter',
        active: true
      },
      {
        name: 'medium',
        active: false
      }
    ];
let arrB = [
      {
        name: 'twitter',
        active: false
      },
      {
        name: 'medium',
        active: false
      }
    ];
let newArr = [];
    
for (var i = 0; i < arrA.length; i++){
  newArr.push({
    name: arrA[i].name,
    active: arrA[i].active || arrB[i].active,
  });
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for that purpose:

```
function MyFunction(firstArray, secondArray) {
    firstArray = firstArray.map(e => {
        if (secondArray.some(_e => _e.name === e.name))
            e.active = e.active || secondArray.filter(f => f.name == e.name)[0].active;
            return e;
        });

        return [...newA, ...arrB.filter(e => !arrA.some(s => s.name === e.name))];
}
```